# Gitorious + GIT basic set-up process

Tags: git, gitorious

So I have a basic Gitorious set-up on a temporary AWS instance (just playing around trying to get it to work), which is located here:

http://ec2-54-247-139-166.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

What is the process I should follow to actually connect to a get repository hosted here?

When I try and connect using TortoiseGit, I get stuck with this error:

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

However, I suspect that it's because I don't know what public/private keys to use where to set everything up properly.

Basically now I have a web set-up, what do I do?

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

The two protocols displayed from one of your Gitorious repo are git and https, so public and private ssh keys are not involved here.

You only need to to https address (like http://git.ec2-54-247-139-166.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test2/test2.git for [test2](http://ec2-54-247-139-166.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test2)), with the right credentials (login+password).

Comment: Thanks VonC. Do I need to set up a further domain name for the "git.ecxyz"? Currently that domain name does not resolve, but I don't know whether the "git." sub-domain is treated separately by the client?

Comment: @MattRogers the domain name should resolve. Or it is a setting Gitorious which adds the 'git' in front of `ec2-54-247-139-166.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`. Does that last part resolve?